# xrdp showing "blue" screen on login, related topics haven't helped so far

Tags: login, remote-desktop, vnc, mate, xrdp

I'm trying to remotely access my ubuntu virtual machine.
I have xrdp and the mate environment installed.

This is my .xsession file in my home directory:

mate-session

this is my /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

if test -r /etc/default/locale; then
        . /etc/default/locale
        test -z "${LANG+x}" || export LANG
        test -z "${LANGUAGE+x}" || export LANGUAGE
        test -z "${LC_ADDRESS+x}" || export LC_ADDRESS
        test -z "${LC_ALL+x}" || export LC_ALL
        test -z "${LC_COLLATE+x}" || export LC_COLLATE
        test -z "${LC_CTYPE+x}" || export LC_CTYPE
        test -z "${LC_IDENTIFICATION+x}" || export LC_IDENTIFICATION
        test -z "${LC_MEASUREMENT+x}" || export LC_MEASUREMENT
        test -z "${LC_MESSAGES+x}" || export LC_MESSAGES
        test -z "${LC_MONETARY+x}" || export LC_MONETARY
        test -z "${LC_NAME+x}" || export LC_NAME
        test -z "${LC_NUMERIC+x}" || export LC_NUMERIC
        test -z "${LC_PAPER+x}" || export LC_PAPER
     test -z "${LC_TELEPHONE+x}" || export LC_TELEPHONE
        test -z "${LC_TIME+x}" || export LC_TIME
        test -z "${LOCPATH+x}" || export LOCPATH
fi

#test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
#startxfce4



#original:
#test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession

#modified:
#export LOGNAME=$USER
#export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1

mate-session
#gnome-session
#startxfce4
#unity
```

Once I try to connect to the ubuntu server from windows I just get a "blue" screen immediately.
If I log in via Remmina from the VM the xrdp menu is shown, however Xorg ends up in a blue screen as well after entering my credentials.

This is the debug log from `xrdp -ns` when conneccting from Windows

```
    g_mk_temp_dir: /var/run/xrdp/sockdir does not exist
[20180125-16:53:06] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 5178
[20180125-16:53:06] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20180125-16:53:09] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.178.27 port 58678
[20180125-16:53:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.178.32 port 3389)
g_mk_temp_dir: /var/run/xrdp/sockdir does not exist
[20180125-16:53:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20180125-16:53:09] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20180125-16:53:09] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20180125-16:53:09] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
ssl_tls_accept: TLS connection accepted
ssl_tls_print_error: SSL_read: I/O error
libxrdp_force_read: error
xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
got XRDP SIGPIPE(13)
got XRDP SIGPIPE(13)
ssl_tls_print_error: SSL_shutdown: I/O error
[20180125-16:53:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.178.32 port 3389)
xrdp_mcs_disconnect - socket closed
[20180125-16:53:09] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state, terminating listener
[20180125-16:53:10] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.178.27 port 58679
[20180125-16:53:10] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.178.32 port 3389)
g_mk_temp_dir: /var/run/xrdp/sockdir does not exist
[20180125-16:53:10] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20180125-16:53:10] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20180125-16:53:10] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20180125-16:53:10] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
ssl_tls_accept: TLS connection accepted
colorDepth 0xca01 (0xca00 4bpp 0xca01 8bpp)
postBeta2ColorDepth 0xca01 (0xca00 4bpp 0xca01 8bpp 0xca02 15bpp 0xca03 16bpp 0xca04 24bpp)
highColorDepth 0x0018 (0x0004 4bpp 0x0008 8bpp 0x000f 15bpp 0x0010 16 bpp 0x0018 24bpp)
supportedColorDepths 0x000f (0x0001 24bpp 0x0002 16bpp 0x0004 15bpp 0x0008 32bpp)
earlyCapabilityFlags 0x07af (0x0002 want32)
got client client connection type 0x00000006
xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data_CS_SECURITY:
  client supports 40 bit encryption
  client supports 128 bit encryption
  client supports 56 bit encryption
  client supports fips encryption
error unknown xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data tag 0xc006 size 8
error unknown xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data tag 0xc00a size 8
xrdp_sec_out_mcs_data: using no security
xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: keyboard_type [4] keyboard_subtype [0]
xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: model [] variant [] layout [de] options []
xrdp_caps_process_order: bitmap cache v3 supported
xrdp_caps_process_pointer: client supports new(color) cursor
xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 10485760 MB cache entries 100
xrdp_caps_process_surface_cmds:
  cmdFlags 0x00000052
xrdp_caps_process_frame_ack:
  max_unacknowledged_frame_count 2
xrdp_process_capset_window wnd_support_level 2 wnd_num_icon_caches 3 wnd_num_icon_cache_entries 12
xrdp_caps_process_codecs: nscodec, codec id 1, properties len 3
xrdp_caps_process_codecs: unknown codec id 5
xrdp_caps_process_codecs: RemoteFX, codec id 3, properties len 49
yeah, up_and_running
xrdp:xrdp_bitmap [0772135206]: xrdp_bitmap_create: noorders
[20180125-16:53:10] [DEBUG] xrdp_0000143c_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
xrdp:xrdp_mm [0772135213]: xrdp_mm_create: bpp 32 mcs_connection_type 6 jpeg_codec_id 0 v3_codec_id 0 rfx_codec_id 3 h264_codec_id 0
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772135213]: xrdp_encoder_create: starting rfx codec session
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse2
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse3
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse4.1
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse4.2
rfxcodec_encode_create: got popcnt
rfxcodec_encode_create: got lzcnt
rfxcodec_encode_create: rfx_encode set to rfx_encode_component_rlgr3_amd64_sse41
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772135214]: init_xrdp_encoder: initializing encoder codec_id 3
[20180125-16:53:10] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000407.ini
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772135217]: proc_enc_msg: thread is running
[20180125-16:53:10] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000407 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
xrdp_wm_login_mode_changed: login_mode is 0
in xrdp_wm_init:
   xrdp_wm_init: no autologin / auto run detected, draw login window
xrdp:xrdp_cache [0772135226]: xrdp_cache_add_bitmap: reset detected cache_id 2
xrdp:xrdp_cache [0772135228]: xrdp_cache_add_bitmap: reset detected cache_id 1
out xrdp_wm_init:
xrdp_wm_login_mode_changed: login_mode is 1
^Cshutting down
signal 2 threadid 140568052193088
[20180125-16:54:58] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
shutting down
signal 2 threadid 140568052193088
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772243225]: proc_enc_msg: global term
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772243225]: proc_enc_msg: thread exit
ssl_tls_print_error: SSL_shutdown: I/O error
[20180125-16:54:58] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.178.32 port 3389)
root@ubuntuvm:/home/schule# xrdp_mcs_disconnect - socket closed
[20180125-16:54:58] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772243231]: xrdp_encoder_delete:
[20180125-16:54:59] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state, terminating listener
^C
root@ubuntuvm:/home/schule# nano .xsession
root@ubuntuvm:/home/schule# nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
root@ubuntuvm:/home/schule# xrdp -ns
g_mk_temp_dir: /var/run/xrdp/sockdir does not exist
[20180125-16:58:48] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 5250
[20180125-16:58:48] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20180125-16:58:50] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.178.27 port 58769
[20180125-16:58:50] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.178.32 port 3389)
g_mk_temp_dir: /var/run/xrdp/sockdir does not exist
[20180125-16:58:50] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20180125-16:58:50] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20180125-16:58:50] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20180125-16:58:50] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
ssl_tls_accept: TLS connection accepted
ssl_tls_print_error: SSL_read: I/O error
libxrdp_force_read: error
xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
got XRDP SIGPIPE(13)
got XRDP SIGPIPE(13)
ssl_tls_print_error: SSL_shutdown: I/O error
[20180125-16:58:50] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.178.32 port 3389)
xrdp_mcs_disconnect - socket closed
[20180125-16:58:50] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state, terminating listener
[20180125-16:58:52] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.178.27 port 58770
[20180125-16:58:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.178.32 port 3389)
g_mk_temp_dir: /var/run/xrdp/sockdir does not exist
[20180125-16:58:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20180125-16:58:52] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20180125-16:58:52] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20180125-16:58:52] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
ssl_tls_accept: TLS connection accepted
colorDepth 0xca01 (0xca00 4bpp 0xca01 8bpp)
postBeta2ColorDepth 0xca01 (0xca00 4bpp 0xca01 8bpp 0xca02 15bpp 0xca03 16bpp 0xca04 24bpp)
highColorDepth 0x0018 (0x0004 4bpp 0x0008 8bpp 0x000f 15bpp 0x0010 16 bpp 0x0018 24bpp)
supportedColorDepths 0x000f (0x0001 24bpp 0x0002 16bpp 0x0004 15bpp 0x0008 32bpp)
earlyCapabilityFlags 0x07af (0x0002 want32)
got client client connection type 0x00000006
xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data_CS_SECURITY:
  client supports 40 bit encryption
  client supports 128 bit encryption
  client supports 56 bit encryption
  client supports fips encryption
error unknown xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data tag 0xc006 size 8
error unknown xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data tag 0xc00a size 8
xrdp_sec_out_mcs_data: using no security
xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: keyboard_type [4] keyboard_subtype [0]
xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: model [] variant [] layout [de] options []
xrdp_caps_process_order: bitmap cache v3 supported
xrdp_caps_process_pointer: client supports new(color) cursor
xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 10485760 MB cache entries 100
xrdp_caps_process_surface_cmds:
  cmdFlags 0x00000052
xrdp_caps_process_frame_ack:
  max_unacknowledged_frame_count 2
xrdp_process_capset_window wnd_support_level 2 wnd_num_icon_caches 3 wnd_num_icon_cache_entries 12
xrdp_caps_process_codecs: nscodec, codec id 1, properties len 3
xrdp_caps_process_codecs: unknown codec id 5
xrdp_caps_process_codecs: RemoteFX, codec id 3, properties len 49
yeah, up_and_running
xrdp:xrdp_bitmap [0772476661]: xrdp_bitmap_create: noorders
[20180125-16:58:52] [DEBUG] xrdp_00001484_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
xrdp:xrdp_mm [0772476669]: xrdp_mm_create: bpp 32 mcs_connection_type 6 jpeg_codec_id 0 v3_codec_id 0 rfx_codec_id 3 h264_codec_id 0
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772476669]: xrdp_encoder_create: starting rfx codec session
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse2
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse3
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse4.1
rfxcodec_encode_create: got sse4.2
rfxcodec_encode_create: got popcnt
rfxcodec_encode_create: got lzcnt
rfxcodec_encode_create: rfx_encode set to rfx_encode_component_rlgr3_amd64_sse41
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772476670]: init_xrdp_encoder: initializing encoder codec_id 3
[20180125-16:58:52] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000407.ini
xrdp:xrdp_encoder [0772476673]: proc_enc_msg: thread is running
[20180125-16:58:52] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000407 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
xrdp_wm_login_mode_changed: login_mode is 0
in xrdp_wm_init:
   xrdp_wm_init: no autologin / auto run detected, draw login window
xrdp:xrdp_cache [0772476690]: xrdp_cache_add_bitmap: reset detected cache_id 2
xrdp:xrdp_cache [0772476691]: xrdp_cache_add_bitmap: reset detected cache_id 1
out xrdp_wm_init:
xrdp_wm_login_mode_changed: login_mode is 1
```

What am I missing / doing wrong? I have tried other solutions mentioned in similar questions / threads on the internet, but none of them worked for me. Tried a different desktop environment and re-installed xrdp.

I hope you can tell me how to solve this issue :)

Comment: You've stated the issue really well. Did you ever figure out what's going on with it?

Comment: I was having this issue as well. Dumb mistake on my part - the rdp blue screen had scrollbars and the login dialog was in the middle of the screen as-expected.